# Converting xml to csv using groovy

Tags: xml, csv, groovy, xml-parsing, export-to-csv

I am trying to convert the below XML to CSV using groovy `XmlSlurper().parseText()`, but nothing is printed when moving to inner node.

### Xml File :

```
 string input = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<executeQueryInSpaceResponse>
    <executeQueryInSpaceResult>
        <rows>
            <ArrayOfString>
                <string>ABCDEF</string>
                <string>ABC</string>
                <string>DEF</string>
                <string>Shilo</string>
                <string/>
                <string>August</string>
                <string>Georgia</string>
                <string/>
                <string>34566</string>
                <string>Studies </string>
                <string>August</string>
                <string/>
                <string/>
                <string>Clerk</string>
                <string/>
                <string>2016-01-05 00:00:00.000</string>
                <string/>
                <string/>
                <string/>
                <string/>
                <string/>
                <string>Not Qualified</string>
                <string>Unintended Request</string>
                <string>512544989</string>
                <string>marketing</string>
                <string>Interactive</string>
                <string/>
                <string>0</string>
            </ArrayOfString>
            <ArrayOfString>
                <string>ABCDEF</string>
                <string>ABC</string>
                <string>DEF</string>
                <string>Shilo</string>
                <string/>
                <string>August</string>
                <string>Georgia</string>
                <string/>
                <string>34566</string>
                <string>Studies </string>
                <string>August</string>
                <string/>
                <string/>
                <string>Clerk</string>
                <string/>
                <string>2016-01-05 00:00:00.000</string>
                <string/>
                <string/>
                <string/>
                <string/>
                <string/>
                <string>Not Qualified</string>
                <string>Unintended Request</string>
                <string>512544989</string>
                <string>marketing</string>
                <string>Interactive</string>
                <string/>
                <string>0</string>
            </ArrayOfString>
        </rows>
        <columnNames>
            <string>Name</string>
            <string>First Name</string>
            <string>Last Name</string>
            <string>Address Line 1</string>
            <string>Address Line 2</string>
            <string>City</string>
            <string>State</string>
            <string>Country</string>
            <string>Postal Code</string>
            <string>Program</string>
            <string>Campus Name</string>
            <string>Date ASP</string>
            <string>Date LEGACY</string>
            <string>Success 1</string>
            <string>Success 2</string>
            <string>Received Date</string>
            <string>Submitted Date</string>
            <string>Complete Date</string>
            <string>Decision Date</string>
            <string>Registration Date</string>
            <string>FDOC</string>
            <string>Status</string>
            <string>Step</string>
            <string>LeadId</string>
            <string>Source</string>
            <string>Vendor</string>
            <string>Client</string>
            <string>SAVEDEXPRESSION</string>
        </columnNames>
        <displayNames>
            <string>Name</string>
            <string>First Name</string>
            <string>Last Name</string>
            <string>Address Line 1</string>
            <string>Address Line 2</string>
            <string>City</string>
            <string>State</string>
            <string>Country</string>
            <string>Postal Code</string>
            <string>Program</string>
            <string>Campus Name</string>
            <string>Date ASP</string>
            <string>Date LEGACY</string>
            <string>Success 1</string>
            <string>Success 2</string>
            <string>Received Date</string>
            <string>Submitted Date</string>
            <string>Complete Date</string>
            <string>Decision Date</string>
            <string>Registration Date</string>
            <string>FDOC Date</string>
            <string>Status</string>
            <string>Step</string>
            <string>LeadId</string>
            <string>Source</string>
            <string>Vendor</string>
            <string>Client</string>
            <string>SAVEDEXPRESSION</string>
        </displayNames>
        <dataTypes>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>93</int>
            <int>93</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>93</int>
            <int>93</int>
            <int>93</int>
            <int>93</int>
            <int>93</int>
            <int>93</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>12</int>
            <int>-5</int>
        </dataTypes>
        <numRowsReturned>10</numRowsReturned>
        <hasMoreRows>false</hasMoreRows>
    </executeQueryInSpaceResult>
</executeQueryInSpaceResponse>"""
```

### Groovy Code :

```
content = new XmlSlurper().parseText(input)
println content
println content.executeQueryInSpaceResponse.executeQueryInSpaceResult
```

It is not printing anything. The expected output will be like,

### Expected Output CSV File:

The header of the csv file should be :

```
Name,First Name,Last Name,Address Line 1,Address Line 2,City,State,Country,Postal Code,Program,Campus Name,Date ASP,Date LEGACY,Success 1,Success 2,Received Date,Submitted Date,Complete Date,Decision Date,Registration Date,FDOC Date,Status,Step,LeadId,Source,Vendor,Client,SAVEDEXPRESSION
```

And the Rows should be,

```
ABCDEF,ABC,DEF,Shilo,,August,Georgia,,34566,Studies,August,,,Clerk,,2016-01-05 00:00:00.000,,,,,,Not Qualified,Unintended Request,512544989,marketing,Interactive,,0
ABCDEF,ABC,DEF,Shilo,,August,Georgia,,34566,Studies,August,,,Clerk,,2016-01-05 00:00:00.000,,,,,,Not Qualified,Unintended Request,512544989,marketing,Interactive,,0
```

Answer (score 0):

The line you put inside the code will return you the `root` node of the xml.

`content = new XmlSlurper().parseText(input)`

If you put `content.executeQueryInSpaceResponse` will return nothing. because the `content` is your root node `executeQueryInSpaceResponse`. Both are same.

you need to replace the code as shown below :

`println content.executeQueryInSpaceResult`

and also I suggest you to refer [Groovy-XML Parsing](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html). Enjoy Coding !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet to help you:

```
def header = content.executeQueryInSpaceResult.columnNames.children().collect().join(',')
def csv = content.executeQueryInSpaceResult.rows.children().inject(header){ result, row ->
 [result, row.children().collect().join(',')].join("\n")
}
```